# How to find location of the Microsoft Machine Learning Server installation files in SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRWUA.png)

I am stuck here and can't find location of the Microsoft Machine Learning Server installation files. If any one know please answer on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

download all 4 *.cab files in 4 different links into the same folder on disk... and choose this folder when pressed "Browse"...and that's it